# How to translate delaunayTriangulation to octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, delaunay

I want to use [GPFR ( matlab program)](https://github.com/PioKow/GRPF) in Octave : GNU Octave, version 6.2.0

```
error: 'delaunayTriangulation' undefined near line 47, column 47

The 'delaunayTriangulation' function is not yet implemented in Octave.
```

so I have changed to [Octave function](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Delaunay-Triangulation.html)

```
%    DT = delaunayTriangulation(NodesCoord(:,1),NodesCoord(:,2)); 
    DT = delaunay(NodesCoord(:,1),NodesCoord(:,2));
```

but it not works:

```
Evaluation of the function in 1992 new points...
Triangulation and analysis of 1992 nodes...
error: matrix cannot be indexed with .
error: called from
    GRPF at line 49 column 14
```

How to translate delaunayTriangulation to octave ?